# How do I install Google Integrated System Conky on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, conky

I am trying to install Google Integrated System Conky
on my machine.  [Here is the link](https://github.com/mustafaozhan/GoogleIntegratedSystemConky) which I am following.
I have followed the guide step by step. All the file were downloaded and present in my home directory as `GoogleintegratedSystemConky`. I have also run the script present in `gisc.sh` but nothing is happening. I have no idea what to do next. Please help me configure this in my machine.
Thanks in advance.

errors:

```
conky: Syntax error (conkyrc:2: '=' expected near 'yes') while reading config file. 
conky: Assuming it's in old syntax and attempting conversion.
conky: desktop window (200014) is subwindow of root window (2ac)
conky: drawing to desktop window
conky: drawing to double buffer
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  145 (DOUBLE-BUFFER)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  1 (DBEAllocateBackBufferName)
  Serial number of failed request:  75
  Current serial number in output stream:  76

conky: Syntax error (conkyKeepRc:2: unexpected symbol near '#') while reading config file. 
conky: Assuming it's in old syntax and attempting conversion.
conky: desktop window (200014) is subwindow of root window (2ac)
conky: window type - override
conky: drawing to created window (0x2600001)
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  1 (X_CreateWindow)
  Serial number of failed request:  73
  Current serial number in output stream:  77
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79581/discussion-on-question-by-c-j-how-do-i-install-google-integrated-system-conky-on).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for those disappointing long comment discussion. This is the best I could do. But the configuration poor. It have braking and will take lot of your time.

This is what I did.

1) I have teejeetech conky manager. You have to install the same.

http://www.teejeetech.in/p/conky-manager.html

2) I have downloaded the zip file, of mustafaozhan/GoogleIntegratedSystemConky and extracted in folder the folder ~/.config

3) Created a new folder in ~/.conky folder and copied the files conkyrc and conkyKeepRc

4) Opened the conky manager and run the code.

5) Set the background image give in background folder

[image]

[image]

Warning: You have to try this on your own risk. For me the conky flicker and hangs the computer.

I am not good at python. Further you are on your own. Just share the details if you have managed to fix it. I will too use this conky.